# What are the parts of a logarithm called?

Tags: logarithms, terminology

$$\log_x y = z$$

$x$ is the base.

$z$ is the exponent or power.

What's $y$ called?

Comment: I had "the logarithm of a number is the index to which the base is raised to equal that number" drilled into me 60 years ago. It's still helpful when I need a reminder what does what. In this context, y is the number, x is the base and y is the index.

Answer (score 8):

I would just call it the argument, it makes sense of thinking of $\log_x$ as an operator, which is applied to an argument. So I would say that $y$ is the argument for the operator $\log_x$ when looking at the expression $\log_x(y)$.

Comment: I think "argument" is probably the best word, but could be very confusing - for instance, in the complex numbers, "the imaginary part of a logarithm is the argument of the argument."

Comment: yeah, you're right, especially because in some settings it might be natural to wonder what the complex argument of a logarithm is. Although in reality I don't think an actual name is needed for the number for which the log is being calculated.

Comment: Although if argument is understood as an "input" to a function, it shouldn't be strange to have an argument within an argument if one has any familiarity with composition.

Comment: In the days of tables, you did not look up the logrithm of 2187, like you do now.  Instead, the tables ran from 1 to 10, so you looked up the log of 2.187.  (but the decimal point wasn't there so it was 2187 meant 2,187  and got a number 339848.  The number 339848 is the 'mantisa', is the log of 2.187.  To get the log of 2187, you needed to add an exponent, here '3' because it's between 10*3 and 10^4.  So the log is 3.339848.  When dealing with numbers less than 1, you have a negative exponent and a positive mantissa, written as with a bar over the exp, eg -3+0.339848.

Comment: When one takes the integral, the function argument is called the integrand. For a derivative, I don't think I've ever heard the term "derivand" to describe the function argument. Moving from functionals back to functions, the arguments of +(a,b) = a+b are typically referred to as summands. Maybe "integrand" exists as a continuum generalization of "summand," OR the "-and" suffix might be old terminology that has fallen out of favor? I have this vague memory that I've heard the argument of the logarithm called a "logand" (or maybe it was "logarand"?) at some point ages ago.

Answer (score 4):

In the days when people used logithm tables, the integer part was the characteristic, and the decimal was the mantissa.

So $\log 20 = 1.30103$, makes 1 the characteristic (the bit after E...)and 0.30103 the mantissa (which the log tables tell you).

In $b^n = x$ or $\operatorname{lg}_b x = n$, b is the base, and n is the exponent, x is the argument of the function.

Comment: I remember using those tables for multiplication and division in school in the 1960s. 60 years on, the logs for 2 and 3 are indelibly printed in my mind. To only four digits, unfortunately. (I could remedy that but such knowledge seems less relevant these days...)

Answer (score 3):

As I learned it, $y$ in your equation *is* the "power."

$z$ is very sharply the "exponent" (or "logarithm"), *not* the power.  However, I also learned that few people make this sharp of a distinction.

"The fifth power of two" is equal to $32$.  Is thirty-two an exponent?  Of course not.

Is it a *power*?  Well, I just said so in the question, didn't I?

Which power is it?  The fifth power of two, of course.  $5$ isn't the *power.*  It's *which* power (of what base) is being referred to.

$2$ is the base.  $5$ is the exponent.  $32$ is the *power.*

You can retain these words regardless of whether the equation you reference is a logarithm or exponentiation.